# Cocos2d animation on sprite and detect contact on him

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I know how to detect contact on all of my sprites that on screen .
I also know how to run animation forever on a sprite .

But when puting together the code for animation, with sprite sheet- you dont actually add the sprite as a child, but ONLY the sprite-sheet, than the sprite is a child of the sprite-sheet.

```
 [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"parrot.plist"];
    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [ CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"parrot.png"];

    fireBall=[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"parrot1.png"];
    fireBall.position=point;
     [spriteSheet addChild:fireBall];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];
    //here animation action perform on fireBall
```

In that case when looking for the `fireBall` for contact detection - you cant find him because he is not added as a child of the scene ,but of the sprite sheet.

How can i detect that sprite later on my code ? or there is another constellation to set the sprite sheet ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your `fireBall` sprite normally, like any other sprite...

There's some ways:

1) Create a property for your `fireBall` sprite:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *fireBall;
```

And create and use it using `self.fireball`:

```
self.fireBall=[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"parrot1.png"];
...
CGPoint fireBallPosition = self.fireBall.position;
```

2) Add `fireBall` as child on `spriteSheet` using tag, and get it back using the same tag.

```
 [spriteSheet addChild:fireBall z:0 tag:1];
 ...
 theFireBall = [spriteSheet getChildByTag:1];
```

But keep in mind that the `fireBall` position is relative of their parent, `spriteSheet`. So, if you move `spriteSheet`, you will also move `spriteSheet`.